# iphone add notification icon to uitoolbar

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, uitoolbar

i am building an application which every 5 minutes get new data from server. i want to notify user with the number of new data added to his previous ones. i am using tool bar and i want to show this icon in a specific place. see the code i used:

```
// notification button
UIButton *notifications=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
notifications.bounds = CGRectMake( 40, 34, 20,20 );
[notifications setTitle:@"1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
notifications.backgroundColor = [ UIColor clearColor];
[notifications addTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


// add to uibutton
UIBarButtonItem *notify = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:notifications];

items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: add, search,flexItem,currentLoc,notify,logoLabel, nil];
```

but the button is not showing in the place declared (40,30),, any help ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass UIButton as :

```
// notification button
UIButton *notifications=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
notifications.bounds = CGRectMake( 40, 34, 20,20 );
[notifications setTitle:@"1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
notifications.backgroundColor = [ UIColor clearColor];
[notifications addTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// Pass your button in UIBarButtonItem here 
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:notifications];
[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:barButton]];
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: i did that but i do not added the full code when i ask the question, i updated the question

Comment: the notification button is shown exactly before the "logo" not in the coordination is set

Comment: yes because these button sequence will be similar to the array you have passed. If you need to display it at different location the change the order of array.

Comment: the order is fine with me,, i want to but notification button in the top left of the logo .. like facebook.. but here it dose not even change x coordination nether y coordination